# Circular linked list: Infinite loop

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm trying to make a circular link list but i'm facing with a problem.

If i run the program with those 2 lines of code above, when i compile and run, it gets an infinite loop of cin if the number of elements is higher than 2. Without them works fine but it isn't anymore a circular linked list. Can you help ?

The problem is right here:

```
toPush->next = head;
head->pred = toPush;
```

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef int data;

// Nodes

struct elements {
    data value;
    elements* next;
    elements* pred;
};

// Function that pushes the element to the end

void insertElementEnding(elements* &head, data var) {
    elements* toPush = new elements;
    toPush->value = var;
    toPush->next = NULL;
    toPush->pred = NULL;
    if(head == NULL) {
        head = toPush;
    } else {
        elements* node = new elements;
        node = head;
        while(node->next != NULL) {
            node = node->next;
        }

        node->next = toPush;
        toPush->pred = node;
        toPush->next = head;
        head->pred = toPush;
    }
}

// Function that prints the list

void showList(elements* head, int numbers) {
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers && head != NULL; i++) {
        cout << head->value;
        head = head->next;
    }
}

int main() {
    elements* head = NULL;
    int var, n;

    cout << "Introduce the number of elements: ";
    cin >> n;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> var;
        insertElementEnding(head, var);
    }

    showList(head, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unrelated rather than `typedef int data;` consider defining `elements` [as a template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates).

Answer (score 3):

You need to look for the start of the loop, not NULL, ie

```
while(node->next != NULL)
```

should be

```
while(node->next != head)
```

As a sidenote, you should use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` in C++.

Also you have a memory leak in your program. You dont need to allocate new memory just to get a pointer for iterating your list. This right here is the problem:

```
elements* node = new elements;
node = head;
```

A better way would just be

```
elements* node = head;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, validation for NULL makes sense only to check if the list is not initialized, before inserting the first element in it.

For all other cases it is redundant as the head should always have previous and following elements for the circle. In case it is just one in the least, it points to itself.

Then if you change the function slightly, it will resolve the problem

```
void insertElementEnding(elements* &head, data var) {

    elements* toPush = new elements;
    toPush->value = var;

    if(head == NULL) {
        head = toPush;
        head->next = toPush;
        head->pred = toPush;
    } else {
        // insert the new element before the head
        head->pred->next = toPush;
        head->pred = toPush;
    }
}
```